# surface and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to proof that surface measure $\sigma_m$ on manifold $M$ and Lebesgue measure $\lambda_m$ coincides on Borel sets. I know that I have to use that locally, $M$ is very well approximated by its tangent space (is it obvious?), but I don't know how, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the _deifnitions_ of $\sigma_n$ and $\lambda_n$? Where I come from there's no such thing as "Lebesgue measure" except on $\Bbb R^n$...

Comment: $\lambda_n$ is defined with respect to the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^m$ restricted to $M$ ($m>n$)